# How to set a VSTO variable with VBA code?

Tags: vba, visual-studio, vsto

I want to prevent the user from saving the VSTO project.

```
Public Class ThisWorkbook
Private Sub ThisApplication_WorkbookBeforeSave(Wb As Workbook, SaveAsUI As Boolean, ByRef Cancel As Boolean) Handles ThisApplication.WorkbookBeforeSave
    Cancel = True
End Sub
end Class
```

My goal is to set one variable like VbaSave (as Boolean) and with one sub in VBA assign True or False at this variable then save or not the project.

The new code in my head will be:

in VSTO

```
Public Class ThisWorkbook
public VbaSave as Boolean = false

Private Sub ThisApplication_WorkbookBeforeSave(Wb As Workbook, SaveAsUI As Boolean, ByRef Cancel As Boolean) Handles ThisApplication.WorkbookBeforeSave
    if VbaSave= false then Cancel = True
End Sub
end Class
```

In a VBA module

```vb
sub mysave()
    myPath = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:= _
      "Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", title:="Save PO", _
      InitialFileName:=ThisWorkbook.Path)
                    
    If myPath = "Falso" Then
        msgStr = "ATTENTION !!!" & vbCrLf & "operazione annullata," & vbCrLf & _
          "nessun file verrà salvato."
        MsgBox msgStr, vbInformation, "Revi4Utility.Info"
        GoTo done
    Else
        VbaSave=true
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs fileName:=myPath
        VbaSave=false
    End If
end sub
```

This example crashes when I run `mysave`. The debug told me that `VbaSave` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

I created a public Boolean variable on VBA, and one function to retrieve the variable value.
In VSTO with `.Application.Run` I call the VBA function and I get the value.

VBA code:

```vb
' I define boolean value
Public SysSave As Boolean  'and I assign False like a STD value on my Ribbon load
    
'one function to get SysSave value  
Function CanSave() As Boolean
    CanSave = SysSave
End Function

' the sub to save the file  
sub mysave()
    myPath = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:= _
      "Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", title:="Save PO", _
      InitialFileName:=ThisWorkbook.Path)
    If myPath = "Falso" Then
        msgStr = "ATTENTION !!!" & vbCrLf & "operazione annullata," & vbCrLf & "nessun file verrà salvato."
        MsgBox msgStr, vbInformation, "Revi4Utility.Info"
        GoTo done
    Else
        SysSave=true
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs fileName:=myPath
        SysSave=false
    End If
end sub
```

VSTO code:

```
'Then I change the VSTO code
Public Class ThisWorkbook
Public SysSave As Boolean = False

Private Sub ThisApplication_WorkbookBeforeSave(Wb As Workbook, SaveAsUI As Boolean, ByRef Cancel As Boolean) Handles ThisApplication.WorkbookBeforeSave
    SysSave = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.Run("CanSave")
    If SysSave = False Then Cancel = True
End Sub

End Class
```